# What are the common tools used for creating graphs using hadoop as the source of data

Tags: graph, hadoop

I was wondering what tools are people using when they need to generate graphs from big data sources, like hadoop?

I've heard of Graphite, but it seems to be more of a realtime graphicing tool, and that not really what I'm looking for.

Right now, my main concern is creating graphs using a big file with data out of a pig script. BTW I've tried using excel, but asides from not being completly happy with the tests results, I fear that if I ever have a **really** big source of data, an excel sheet might not be enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind the command line, Gnuplot works great.